# User defined names for exported pdf files?

Tags: amcharts

Can user define his/her own file name for the exported PDF file in amcharts?.Currently the default name is **amCharts.pdf.**

With reference to the link [AmCharts Export Config](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/exporting-charts-and-maps-to-images-or-pdf/), I saw that the user can programmatically change the default file name used, however he cannot define the file names at run time when export as pdf is clicked.Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @martynasma Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you just want to change the default name of the exported files, or you want physically ask the user to enter the file name when he/she clicks export?

Comment: The later one.Want to ask the user to enter the file name on click of export->pdf.

Comment: Got it. This is most definitely doable. Let me think about it for a moment.

Comment: Do you want the export still to be triggered using the amCharts Export button, or do you have your own button? In the first case i think you have to do it seperately. Like change `chart.export.config.fileName = "new Filename"` then `chart.validateNow()` to accept the change and then export like normal.

Comment: If you have your own button there could be a way to trigger the export manually.

Comment: @gerric I want the export to be triggered using amchart export button with a prompt to enter the filename by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `menuReviver` to attach another `click event handler` to interrupt the runtime with the prompt modal to overwrite the filename.

```
"export": {
  "enabled": true,
  "menuReviver": function( config, li ) {
    var context = this; // INSTANCE

    // MODIFY ONLY IMAGE ITEMS
    if ( config.capture ) {
      var title = li.getElementsByTagName( "span" )[ 0 ].textContent;
      var link = document.createElement( "a" );
      var span = document.createElement( "span" );

      // REMOVE ORIGINAL
      li.getElementsByTagName( "a" )[ 0 ].remove();

      // TITLE
      span.innerHTML = title;
      link.appendChild( span );

      function callback() {
        var fileName = prompt( "Filename" );

        // CHECK FILENAME
        if ( fileName ) {

          // CAPTURE CHART
          this.capture( {}, function() {

            // GET JPG DATA
            this.toPDF( {}, function( base64 ) {
              var info = this.defaults.formats.PDF;

              // OFFER DOWNLOAD WITH GIVEN FILENAME
              this.download( base64, info.mimeType, fileName + info.extension );
            } );
          } );
        }
      }

      // LINK
      link.addEventListener( "click", function() {
        callback.apply( context, arguments );
      } );
      li.appendChild( link );
    }
  }
```

http://codepen.io/amcharts/pen/674b14ad4e2594a31ac59a455dda6784

In case you want to do it manually you can do it like following:

```
"export": {
  "enabled": true,
  "menu": [ {
    "format": "PDF",
    "click": function() {
      var fileName = prompt( "Filename:" );

      // CHECK FILENAME
      if ( fileName ) {

        // CAPTURE CHART
        this.capture( {}, function() {

          // GET JPG DATA
          this.toPDF( {}, function( base64 ) {
            var info = this.defaults.formats.PDF;

            // OFFER DOWNLOAD WITH GIVEN FILENAME
            this.download( base64, info.mimeType, fileName + info.extension );
          } );
        } );
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Great!..Works the way i want, with just one minor glitch. If i cancel the prompt, the file is still downloaded with filename same as the filetype.Any correction for this?

Comment: I've updated my answer. First sample: replaces the "a" element to attach a modified event listener. Second sample: Simply checks the prompt value.

Comment: Hi @Maertz how do you do this if you want more than just one like for example "JPG ,PDF, CSV and ANNOTATE" only

Comment: Just add another item to the menu array. Take a look into the [Github entry](https://github.com/amcharts/export/) there are all options explained or to the knowledge base of amcharts.com.